# Neo4j: inferring related nodes of a different type

Tags: database, algorithm, graph, neo4j, cypher

I would like to use Neo4j to find related professions and skills.

Currently, I am using this query:

```
MATCH (p:Profession {id: 123})<-[:HAS_PROFESSION]-(:User)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(p2)
RETURN p2.id AS professionId, p2.name AS professionName, count(p2) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

It gives me related professions ordered by the number of usages by a User. e.g. if a User has 'graphic designer' and 'photographer' as professions and another user has 'photographer' and 'creative director'. It is able to infer the 'photographer' profession is related to the 'creative director' profession.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this, and more importantly how to find a cluster of related skills. e.g. [creative director, art director, photographer, graphic designer], [software engineer, software developer, web developer, web designer].

I have had a look at [Neo4j Graph Algorithms User Guide](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_community_detection_louvain) but I am unsure what the best algorithm would be, and how to apply it to this relationship: `(:Profession)<-[:HAS_PROFESSION]-(:User)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(:Profession)` rather than simple relationships like `(:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Schema:
[image: Current neo4j schema]